# applying single weight on multiple filters in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-dsl

I want to group multiple filters and apply a common weight to it, but haven't find a solution yet. Tried writing down the filters separately but the result isn't as expected. How can use "AND" operation here and apply 1 weight for a group of latestepisodeTime, publishedOn and listen.

Note:
An album consists of multiple episodes.
PublishedOn refers to the album release date
latestepisodeTime refers to the release date of episode in an album
listen is the times it has been heard

Scenario: some episodes which are released recently but have a decent amount of listens should weigh more than someone who released their episodes few months back and have a significant amount of listens.

Problem:  in the current query same weight is assigned for "x" listens irrespective of when the episode was released.

Thanks

```
   "query" : {
     "boosting" : {
       "positive" : {
         "function_score" : {
           "query" : {
             "dis_max" : {
               "queries" : [
                   { "match" : 
                     { "category.name" :
                       {
                         "query" : "abc",
                         "boost" : 1
                       }
                     }
                   }
                 
                  ]
                }
              },
              "functions" : [{"filter": { 
         "range" : { "latestEpisodeTime": { "gte" : "now-7d", "lte" : "now" } }} ,
         "weight": 1000
     },
     {"filter": { 
        "range" : { "latestEpisodeTime": { "gte" : "now-15d", "lt" : "now-7d" } }} ,
        "weight": 100
      },
     {"filter": { 
        "range" : { "latestEpisodeTime": { "gte" : "now-30d", "lt" : "now-15d" } }} ,
        "weight": 10
      },
     {"filter": { 
        "range" : { "latestEpisodeTime": {"lt" : "now-30d" } }} ,
        "weight": 1
      },
     {"filter": { 
        "range" : { "publishedOn": {  "gte" : "2021-01-01", "lte" : "now" } }} ,
        "weight": 1000
      },{"filter": { 
        "range" : { "publishedOn": {  "gte" : "2020-01-01", "lt" : "2021-01-01" } }} ,
        "weight": 100
      },{"filter": { 
        "range" : { "publishedOn": {  "gte" : "2019-01-01", "lt" : "2020-01-01" } }} ,
        "weight": 10
      },{"filter": { 
        "range" : { "publishedOn": { "lt" : "2019-01-01" } }} ,
        "weight": 1
      },{"filter": { 
        "range" : { "listen": { "lt" : "10000", "gte" : "1000" } }} ,
        "weight": 1000
      },{"filter": { 
        "range" : { "listen": { "lt" : "100000", "gte" : "10000"} }} ,
        "weight": 100
      },{"filter": { 
        "range" : { "listen": { "lt" : "1000000", "gte" : "100000" } }} ,
        "weight": 10
      },{"filter": { 
        "range" : { "listen": { "lt" : "10000000", "gte" : "1000000" } }} ,
        "weight": 1
      }
               
              ]
            }
          },
          "negative" : {
            "match" : { "studio" : "false" }
           },
           "negative_boost" : 0.1
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: can you please explain your use case with the help of some sample data and expected search result ?

Comment: @ESCoder I have edited the question, kindly go through the same.